Wiring a 66DFG-10T single pole device to be used as a dual pole with switches between the device and the fan/light
I have a question that I was hoping this forum could provide me an answer. I have a Leviton 66DF-10T single pole device that controls a fan and a light fixture from one location.  It has a black (hot) line into the unit and two leads out, a red one that controls the fan and a yellow one that controls the light. These are slider switches. What I would like to do is include a switch on the red and yellow leads going out between the 66DF-10T and the fan and light so that I wouldn’t need to keep moving the sliders down when exiting the room. I could simply flip a switch as needed. In addition, I was thinking of making the circuit from the 66DF-10T to the light a two-way circuit, so again, I am controlling switching the light on or off without moving the slider. To a degree, I am putting the cart before the horse. That said, I cannot see why this would not work, but any comments/input/thoughts would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Have you looked at replacing it with a different device that has the appropriate switches built in?

Do you want the fan and light to go on and off together, or independently?
